# ASP.NET vNext, enable compression to IIS 8 on Azure?

Tags: asp.net-core

how would one enable gzip compression of responses with Content-Type application/json when the asp.net 5 app is deployed to IIS 8 on Azure? Typically this would've been done using web.config but that's gone now... what's the new approach?

Comment: Very broad question, and kind of off-topic for Stack Overflow. Kestrel is a development server so I doubt there are any plans to implement compression. If you need advanced hosting features it would be a good idea to use a proper web server in front of kestrel/webhosting. IIS and nginx are both examples that support compression that you can put infront of your kestrel/webhost application. Try creating an issue in the appropriate GitHub repositories and ask there. :)

Comment: Ok, so what we need is a FastCGI implementation of Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting interfaces, actually

Comment: To provide a less broad question, how would one enable gzip compression of responses with Content-Type  `application/json` when the asp.net 5 app is deployed to IIS 8 on Azure?   Typically this would've been [done using `web.config`](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/890b6d25-f7dd-4272-8970-da7798bcf25d/httpcompression-settings-on-a-simple-azure-website?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) but that's gone now... what's the new approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse-proxy your kestrel application, then you can tell the reverse-proxy to compress.

In nginx, this goes as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  server_name localhost;

  gzip            on;
  gzip_min_length 1000;
  #gzip_proxied    expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_vary on;
  gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";


  location /
  {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5004;
  }
}
```

So here nginx will catch incoming requests on port 80, and then forward them to kestrel on the same machine, but on port 5004. Kestrel then sends the response back to nginx. Since gzip is on, nginx will compress the response, and send it to the user. All you need to ensure is that the application on Kestrel does not return HTTP headers, such as HTTP 1.1 chuncked-encoding when outputting for example a file (e.g. when using what used-to-be Response.TransmitFile).

IIS 7.5+ supports reverse proxying.
 
See here for closer information:
 
https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server

Comment: I don't think kestrel is a viable solution. it's a dev server

Comment: @gua from mars: No arguments from me there. That's why you put IIS/nginx in front (for SSL/virtual name based hosting, etc.). Since there is no fastcgi, you can only do reverse-proxying.  And you're using a pre-release version of MVC, so you're not good for production anyway.

Comment: Why to use GZIP then ? I'm looking for a solution to put in production when MVC6 will be released

Comment: @agua from mars: Because from IIS to kestrel, you're in the internal network, perhaps even on the same computer (loopback-interface). So if it's uncompressed there, it's not a big performance loss. But as soon as it leaves over the internet, it should be compressed, to minimize load-times.. Whether it is kestrel or iis/nginx who compresses the data, is of no consequence for the user. The only thing that matters for the user is loading time.

Comment: on IIS, no need to use a reverse proxy, we can just configure the web site compression for dynamic and static

Comment: @agua from mars: Yes, but only if the website is hosted on IIS itselfs. If IIS listens on the network card IP at port 80, but your actual application runs under kestrel on port 5004 or so, you'll need to reverse-proxy.